# Using tuple comparison in mysql is it efficient?

Tags: mysql, tuples, sqlperformance

I have a table of books :

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nameOfBook` VARCHAR(32),
    `releaseDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `Index 2` (`releaseDate`, `id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

AUTO_INCREMENT=33029692;

I compared two SQL requests to do a pagiation with sort on releaseDate. Both of theses request return the same result.

(simple one)

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE  id,name, releaseDate  
from books  
where releaseDate <= '2016-11-07'  
AND (releaseDate<'2016-11-07' OR id <    3338191)  
ORDER  by releaseDate DESC, id DESC limit 50;
```

and

(tuple comparison or row comparaison)

```
select SQL_NO_CACHE  id,name, releaseDate 
from books 
where (releaseDate ,id) < ('2016-11-07',3338191) 
ORDER  by releaseDate DESC, id DESC limit 50;
```

When I do the explain of the request i got this

simple one :

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"SIMPLE";"books";"range";"PRIMARY,Index 2";"Index 2";"9";"";"1015876";"Using where; Using index"
```

We can see it is parsing "1015876" of rows

The explain for the tuple comparison :

```
"id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"SIMPLE";"books";"index";"";"Index 2";"13";"";"50";"Using where; Using index"
```

We can see it is parsing "50" of rows.

But if I checked the exectution time the simple one :

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Lignes trouvées: 50  Avertissements: 0  Durée pour 1 query: 0,031 sec. */
```

and the tuple one :

```
/* Affected rows: 0  Lignes trouvées: 50  Avertissements: 0  Durée pour 1 query: 3,682 sec. */
```

I don't understant why according to the explain the tuple comparison is better but the execution time is badly worse?

Comment: The execution plan is the "path" the optimizer will choose, the number of rows parsed doesn't necessarily affect the outcome .

Comment: according to my result test the tuple comparison is less performant than the simple one. Is it a bad practice to use tuple comparison then?

Comment: I'm looking for authoritative description on how tuple comparison uses matching compound indices as well as practical performance.

Comment: @qarma For what it's worth.. an index on `(releaseDate, id)` is effectively the same as an index on just `releaseDate` in this case. [See Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html), "In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index."

Comment: Tuples work great on databases but mysql.

Comment: @Hannes - Alas, one of those half-implemented features in MySQL -- syntax and functionality is there, but performance is not.

Answer (score 16):

I've been irritated by this for years.  `WHERE (a,b) > (1,2)` has never been optimized, in spite of it being easily transformed into the other formulation.  Even the other format was poorly optimized until a few years ago.

Using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` might give you some better clues.

Meanwhile, `EXPLAIN` ignored the `LIMIT` and suggested 1015876.  On many cases, `EXPLAIN` provides a "decent" Row estimate, but not either of these.

Feel free to file a bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com (and post the link here).

Another formulation was recently optimized, in spite of `OR` being historically un-optimizable.

```
where  releaseDate <  '2016-11-07'  
   OR (releaseDate  = '2016-11-07' AND id < 3338191)
```

For measuring query optimizations, I like to do:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Small values, such as '50' for your case, indicate good optimization; large value (1M) indicate a scan.  The Handler numbers are exact; unlike the *estimates* in `EXPLAIN`.

**Update** [*5.7.3*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) has improved handling of tuples, aka "row constructors"

**Update** [MySQL Bug#104128](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104128) covers this.

Comment: This is the same as they recommend [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html). But the example there is a bit different. Reading it, one might assume, that the query in this question should work fine, since the condition here **does** cover the index.

Comment: I read that page as "here's some nifty syntax", not "this will perform well".

Comment: Methinks there are 2 ways to rewrite `(a,b)>(1,2)`: namely `a>1 or a=1 and b>2` and also `a>=1 and (a>1 or b>2)` where at least index on `a` can always be utilised (under some assumptions of data density in `a` and `b`).

Comment: @qarma - I previously did some experiments with 'Handler%'; it turned out that `INDEX(a,b)` worked well for either of the rewrites.  Please try it on your version to confirm.  (And state which MySQL/MariaDB version you are running.)

Comment: I'm only interested in newest open source MySQL version, that's 5.7.x

Comment: @qarma - I _think_ both rewritten versions (but not tuple version) will work fast on 5.7.  I have not tested lately.

Comment: @RickJames - On a table where `a` is always `1`, only the version in your answer is efficient. Tested with MySQL 5.7.18, 1M rows and the condition `a>=1 and (a>1 or b>999900)`. The other version seems only to use key part `a`, which is no help in that case.

Comment: Which technique did you use to determine "efficient"?

Comment: The `FLUSH STATUS`, etc.  But first tack a `LIMIT 1` on the `SELECT`.  If the Handler values were tiny, then it ran efficiently.  If the values felt like the size of the rest of the table, then not.

Comment: Thanks, Jean-François.  A little test showed that it might be fixed.  However I failed to find mention of it in the ChangeLogs.  So, I can't say which specific version fixed it.