# Understanding performance impacts for mysql tuple search

Tags: mysql, database, search, optimization, indexing

I am working on a table structure like this (emp_data)

```
id   dept_id    emp_id   emp_name      role
1      101       1001      Tom      Good Worker
2      101       1002      Dick     Smart Worker
3      102       1001      Harry    Hard Worker
4      103       1001      Kate      Nice Worker
5      101       1003      Lucy     Great Worker
```

- id is the uncontested primary key :)
- (dept_id, emp_id) is a multi column index

Now, I need to do some really big search on combinations on (dept_id, emp_id).

I use tuple search which goes like this.

```
select * from emp_data 
where (dept_id, emp_id) in 
  ((101, 1001), 
   (101, 1002), 
   (103, 1001));
```

This takes quite some time when the table is quite long.

But if i do this,

```
select * from emp_data 
where dept_id in (101, 103) 
and (dept_id, emp_id) in 
((101, 1001), 
 (101, 1002), 
 (103, 1001));
```

It is considerably faster, even 100x.

What I do not understand here is,

- Why is query 1 not fast even though the search is on indexed columns?

---edit---

I did an explain on the two queries on my tables.

- I really am confusing mysql to do a full table scan for the first query. This at least leads to one conclusion - **indexes are useless when working with tuple searches in 'in' clause**.
- The row count for the second query is less than and approx equal to the results. This means **having an indexed column in 'in' clause works**.

So, is it bad to use indexed columns in the in clause?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489417/using-tuple-comparison-in-mysql-is-it-efficient), support for tuples in MySQL is not optimized. As @O.Jones writes in his comment, the query planner in MySQL is a mightily complex beast, and things that *should* work do not always behave as you might expect.

I believe your second query is faster because the first where clause `dept_id in (101, 103)` 
reduces the search space for the second one which uses the tuples. The query optimizer *should* do this automagically, but at least in your example does not do so.

I do not believe the `IN` clause is the problem - it's the tuple comparison which is scanning the entire table and not using available indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is basically an `OR` operation. It needs to look at the table for each distinct tuple you're retrieving. So it repeats the search several times, and it may also baffle the MySQL query planner into doing full-table scans. In that case, it does one for each tuple. That generates really nasty performance.

In your second query, the first clause looks like it narrows your search, then uses the index.

You need to use the `EXPLAIN` feature when troubleshooting this sort of thing.

If you're going into production with a requirement like this, it may be worth your while to do the following pair of queries.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS searchterms AS

  SELECT 101 dept_id, 1001 emp_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 101 dept_id, 1002 emp_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 103 dept_id, 1001 emp_id;

SELECT * 
  FROM emp_data
  JOIN searchterms ON emp_data.dept_id = searchterms.dept_id
                  AND emp_data.emp_id = searchterms.emp_id;
```

The first of these queries puts your tuples into a temp table, and the second uses the table in a `JOIN` operation. It's likely to be optimized better. But you should try it. It's a slight pain to write your program so it creates the temporary table, but this approach scales up more nicely than an `IN ()` clause.

Comment: Isn't having a temp table an overkill. Can you have a look at my edit? Is IN clause that bad?

Comment: I wouldn't have gone to the trouble of suggesting a temp table if I thought it was overkill. Query optimization is a tricky business, because you're trying to second-guess a vast, complex, and constantly changing piece of software in the MySQL server called the query planner. Those of us who *use* MySQL try to come up with ways to get our work done. You asked, and I explained my way of solving your problem. This strategy has worked for me searching for two, or 200, tuples.

Answer (score 0):

For performance purposes it's better not to use **IN** at all.

```
SELECT * 
FROM emp_data 
WHERE (dept_id = 101 AND emp_id = 1001) 
    OR (dept_id = 101 AND emp_id = 1002) 
    OR (dept_id = 103 AND emp_id = 1001)
```

You could use **EXPLAIN** before each request to check how they behaves (actually, in the most cases - indexes became not in use for IN statements).

Comment: Hmm.. is using IN that bad on indexed columns. I believe the EXPLAIN for IN and OR statements will provide similar results?

Comment: Try it... even for primary key it'll differ. Surely, in some cases it can be a milliseconds but for a few projects it was seconds deviation. Also, valuable point that you have combined index (dept_id, emp_id); but even in that case it could differ from index (emp_id, dept_id). It depends for which ID you have less variations.

Comment: The example is something I just made up. I don't have any reservations for using 'IN'. But I just do not see any proof or documentation which says it performs worse than chaining OR statements. I will try to run some more tests. Thanks anyway!!