# Use IN for multiple columns primary key

Tags: mysql, performance

I have two columns primary key (id, id2) in MySql.
Those ids have a direct connection (for id=1 id2=11, for id=2 id=22, ect.)

I was wonder if the following query:

```
select * from my_table where id IN (1,2,3..) AND id2 IN (11,22,33..)
```

Is actually damage the performance, although it is a primary key.

Will run a single select in loop:

```
select * from my_table where id = 1 AND id2 = 11
select * from my_table where id = 2 AND id2 = 22
```

...
run faster?

I believe the answer is yes, cause for each id, the query compare id2 with a list of integers.
Is it correct?
Also, does IN makes a difference for a single column primary key?

Comment: There is a difference between `id IN (1,2,3) AND id2 IN (11,22,33)` and `(id,id2) IN ((1,11,),(2,22),(3,33))`. Which one do you need?

Comment: Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44199208/understanding-performance-impacts-for-mysql-tuple-search

Comment: If id and id2 have a direct connection as you say, you can just do **select * from my_table where id IN (1,2,3..)** because you already know that if id=1 then id2 will be 11

Comment: With the latest releases of MySQL, the optimizer can make use of indexes to satisfy "`(id,id2) IN ( (1,11), (2,22), (3,33) )`".  Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plans, and run tests to evaluate actual performance. (Use tables and values that represent expected use case; don't measure performance using trivial, non-representative sets.)

Comment: "don't measure performance using trivial, non-representative sets.)" @spencer7593 well executing `select * from my_table where id IN (1,2,3..) AND id2 IN (11,22,33..)` vs changing id's in `select * from my_table where id = 1 AND id2 = 11
select * from my_table where id = 2 AND id2 = 22` in a loop... **Both methods will result in the same data in the memory in the application end** right?.. Besides MySQL tends to optimize the `IN()` operator with a **large** list badly.

Comment: ... Besides MySQL tends to optimize the `IN()` operator with a **large** list badly, so you actually might gain performance to use divide and conquer tactics (single queries in a loop)..Most likely better would be to use query parallel execution if your programming language supports threads/forks/processes and merge the results from the threads/forks/processes into a global accessable memory location (most likely a Object or Array in most  programming languages) instead of looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are checking 'most' of the values, then a single query doing a table scan is probably fastest.
- If the `IN` clauses are rather short, the Optimizer *may* hopscotch through the table very efficiently.
- If the table is huge and the values are scattered and disk hits are needed, it may be slow regardless.
- Roughly speaking, 10 1-row `SELECTs` inherently take as long as a single `SELECT` fetching 100 rows.  (This assumes no I/O and good indexes.)  So, you need to be desperate to do single selects.

In other words, *you* test it with *your* data and *your* `IN` lists.  We cannot give you a simple answer.  But beware, as the table grows and/or your `IN` lists change, performance *could* change.