# MySQL: how to update with a filtering vector list?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a list of values that I want to match with the where clause to update a flag.

(col1, col2, col3)

(1, 2, 3)

(2, 3, 4)

(3, 4, 5)

If the filtering list were made by only one column I would have done this way:

```
update mytable 
set flag=1
where col1 in ('1','2','3','5','8','13');
```

Would this query be fit for my purpose?

```
update mytable 
set flag=1
where col1 in ('1','2','3')
and col2 in ('2','3','4')
and col3 in ('3','4','5');
```

If the table had a record (1,3,5) the query would update the flag but the filtering list would not be considered correctly.

Is it possible to use the where clause with all of the columns of my filtering list? For example

```
where (col1, col2, col3) in (???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IN` to compare row constructors (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)).

The following should work:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET flag=1
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN ((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), ...);
```

But as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706196/mysql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause) it might not be the fastest solution.