# Crafting a sequelize WHERE IN using multiple columns

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In MySQL (And other dbs), [you can do a where in query with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44706196/mysql-multiple-columns-in-in-clause) like below:

```
SELECT * FROM trains WHERE (name, location) IN (('train1', 'us'), ... ,('train2', 'us'));
```

I'm trying to do this with sequelize:

```
const selectTrains = [
    {name: 'train1', location: 'us'},
    {name: 'train1', location: 'eu'},
    {name: 'train2', location: 'us'},
];

let dbTrains = await Trains.findAll({ where: { [Op.in]: selectTrains} });
```

But I get the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid value {name: 'train1', location: 'us'}

The documentation didn't really cover this use case. Is this possible to do with the `Op.in` operator?

Comment: In most languages, this ends up just having to be a concatenated string, sadly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing with `$or` :

```
const selectTrains = [
    {name: 'train1', location: 'us'},
    {name: 'train1', location: 'eu'},
    {name: 'train2', location: 'us'},
];

Trains.findAll({ where: { $or : selectTrains} });
```

Comment: I have noticed that I can do this, but it creates a massive OR statement, which is significantly less performant (By almost a factor of 3) than a WHERE IN statement.

Comment: @FrankerZ , then other option is to run raw query via sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of **$or** use **Op.or**        
const selectTrains = [
            {name: 'train1', location: 'us'},
            {name: 'train1', location: 'eu'},
            {name: 'train2', location: 'us'},
];
        
// Trains.findAll({ where: { $or : selectTrains} });
 Trains.findAll({ where: { [**Op.or**] : selectTrains} });
```

Comment: Please add description to your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).