# How to handle null value for tuple comparison in SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm now trying to implement keyset pagination by using SQL tuple comparison. However this will filter out all the null values. So I would like to know if there is a (nice) way to handle such case.

The idea is to use tuple to filter and sort a list based on a primary column and a secondary column (normally it's `id`), following is the sql script for doing this (I take a tinyint column `priority` as primary column)

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE (priority, id) > (2, 1000) 
ORDER BY priority asc, id asc
```

However the `priority` column is nullable (and I would like to keep it this way), so the tuple comparison will filter out all the rows which `priority` is `null`.

I have searched on the internet but there doesn't seem to have any solutions for this problem.

An alternative solution is to use a equivalent sql script instead of tuple comparison, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43457966/1720156), the above sql script could be rewritten as

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE priority >= 2 
AND (priority = 2 AND id > 1000 OR priority > 2) 
ORDER BY priority asc, id asc
```

The complexity for the script increase exponentially as new condition being included. I don't think my head is clear enough to include null check in this script and I'm all ears if anyone have a proper solution for this.

So all I want to know is that how/if tuple comparison for sql can include null values, and what are the alternatives if it doesn't.

Comment: If they have a priority of null, would you like them included or not? If you want them included, can't you do something like `WHERE (ISNULL(priority, 9999), id) > (2, 1000)`?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I think `ISNULL()` can only accept one parameter

Comment: @kyne He probably meant `IFNULL` or better... `COALESCE`.

Comment: I'm used to ISNULL on other engines, SQL Server allows two, probably more like "IFNULL", yes.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, `IFNULL` works for me :) But in this case I need to carefully select the default value for null. I'm still wondering if there are any more generic ways to handle this